# #SNMP - Simple GET

Tags: c#, sharp-snmp

I've been looking at #SNMP, which seems to be the most complete SNMP library in C#. However, I find that the documentation is quite lacking, merely pointing to the source code, which is completely void of comments :-)

Now I'm not a professional developer so this probably comes from me, and surely professional developers can make sense of a complex API by just looking at non-commented code. So I'm looking of a simple implementation of "Get the value of the specified OID."

Would anybody be able to provide the sheer minimum code required to poll equipments using that lib?

Comment: Have you looked at? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9411884/how-to-get-the-name-of-the-oid-snmp

Comment: Yes and it seems fairly incomplete - no remote IP is being specified etc, for instance.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/468892/An-introduction-to-sharpSNMP-an-Open-Source-SNMP

Comment: Thanks Li for posting the answer as a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that a more adequate lib to use is [SNMP Sharp Net](http://www.snmpsharpnet.com/). It's much better documented with a full range of examples, and more features than #SNMP it seems.

Comment: "more than #SNMP" is kind of an illusion, http://www.lextm.com/2012/07/sharpsnmp-vs-snmpsharpnet.html

Comment: Somebody got so pissed he rated down both the answer and the response? Wow :) Maybe I was too subjective. But then again, the blog you quoted states "Fine. As I am the developer of #SNMP, this post must be biased."

Comment: @Astaar - Just fwiw, the "blog [he] quoted" turns out to be *his* blog. Kinda surprised he didn't include some code with the drive-by! ;^) Guess the link to *his* CodeProject post from his earlier comment has the answer. That said, to be fair, this accepted answer (yours, natch; heavy nepotism time at SO here ;^D) doesn't literally answer your question's request for `the sheer minimum code required to poll equipments using that lib [#SNMP]` either.