# SNMP OID Translation with .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, snmp, .net-standard, sharp-snmp

currently I'm using the LexTm Libraries in my .NET Core / Standard 1.3+ class libraries.

Now I need to use the translation function, I have found another posts, but it seems only compatible with FullDotNet.

Anyone has used the OID translation in .Net core ?

i tried to use this but only for fulldotnet
[How to get the name of the Oid (#Snmp)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9411884/how-to-get-the-name-of-the-oid-snmp)

Comment: Only a selected group of users currently has access to the .NET Core version of #SNMP Pro. The official release would be some time after Microsoft releases .NET Core 2.0.

Comment: Thank you, I will keep searching another alternatives.